# Open a html file with already called javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have some local html file called '123.htm'. If I open it, i have an option to press on a 'click here' link and it expands some table in the current page. The 'click here' is in fact a call to some javascript method, that expands that table.

My question is, in another html file, is it possible to create a link that when you press on it, it will open the '123.htm' file, **with the expanded table** (without any need to press the 'click here' link)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any changes to your `123.htm` file, no, I don't believe it's possible.

If you can change the `123.htm` file though, there is a variety of ways you can archieve that.

The first one that comes to my mind is to add some javascript that executes on page load. This Javascript will check the `GET` parameters of your page. If a specific argument is needed, the javascript will open the table. Otherwise (default behavior), it does nothing:

```js
  if (/openTable/.test(location.search)) {
    openTable();
  }
```

That way, when you create the link from the other html page, just write:

```html
<a href="123.htm?openTable">my link</a>
```

Comment: thanks. seems it is not possible without changing it